# Broad Institute and support for OpenWDL on Bioinformatics SE

Tags: discussion, support

I spotted a chat from @Geraldine_VdAuwe, almost certainly Geraldine A. Van der Auwera from the Broad Institute and one of the authors of `Genomics in the Cloud` by O'Reilly. Its a good book, I tracked it because I wanted to assess cross-over with 'driver mutation' stuff.

[24 April 2020](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/58858?m=54184146#54184146),

> On the OpenWDL side, we've chosen this SE as the primary venue for WDL
> community support as it feels like a good fit, both technically and
> culturally. On the Broad side, we're going to follow suit by
> encouraging people to post their Cromwell questions here.

This is good. It would be better formally announced, for example I don't read chat. It would be cool if Broad Institute could assign someone to this site to support the recommendation because there are a fair number of GATK, WDL, Cromwell questions on site. I've looked carefully at all this stuff in my case I decided custom solutions were more appropriate (don't work on human genetics).

Perhaps the Mods could write in a formal capacity to the Broad Institute? Bioinformatics SE has enough kudos: its big brother Stackoverflow is the undisputed heavy weight in online coding help.

**Blurb**
The announcement from Geraldine does make sense because Biostars copyrights help manuals in own its own capacity and sells them. I would assume the proceeds help support the site. However, this would be a problem for the Broad Institute and especially publishing houses such as O'Reilly because there would be legal issues about profiting from Broad Institute products that could block further publishing arrangements. Technically if official help was given on Biostars - that would fall under Biostars copyright. Bioinformatics SE must have external support and is presumably is supported from the advertising revenue of Stackoverflow, which is likely huge. There are some superb coders on Stackoverflow, a famous Perl coder (whose name I forget), is but one. For example, some Python solutions are sublime from coders who are otherwise under the IP of their employers. Bioinformatics SE is important because at present there seems just too much traffic for moderation on Stackoverflow.

---

**Notes on O'Reilly**
O'Reilly is the premier publishing house of coding books. O'Reilly famously published Larry Wall's Perl5 which was the authority on how to code in Perl, albeit it then published Damien Conway's 'Official Perl coding' (forget its title), which was a famous disaster. Who is Damien Conway - good question - he was known for 6-lines of Perl code known as 'whitening' (not very PC), but had published on object orientated Perl elsewhere.

Comment: As additional context, this message was starred by two users (now three), and was responded to in chat.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just to point out, a number of us don't really look at chat, but that would be a good place to raise the above matter.